# How to become redirected to Facebook's Mobile Web URL

Tags: facebook, configuration, facebook-authentication

I would like to integrate an existing, external application with Facebook using *Mobile Web* method and its authenticated referrals as well as to be able to redirect user (incoming from a different place) to Facebook login page. I do not want it to be embedded in Facebook page.

If I understand correctly how the authenticated referrals work, I must somehow reach the authentication dialog which will redirect me to the `Mobile Web URL`, which I specified in the application configuration.

Additional information: I would like to avoid making the application public until it is ready, so I have set the `Sandbox Mode` setting to `Enabled`.

How to get the URL, with which I will be able to test authenticated referrals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can land at your game's `Mobile Web URL` page using following steps:

- Switch your user agent to `iPhone` or other mobile.
- Go to the http://m.facebook.com page.
- Press the "identity" icon in the top left edge of the screen to show the bookmarks menu.
- Look for the application in the `Apps` section.
- Press the application bookmark.

Above procedure worked for me. My user was an admin of the project but it will probably work also for devs and testers (just a guess).